# Resize a UITableView to accommodate a translucent header before it becomes visible

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have a UITableView inside a UINavigationController.  The navigation controller uses a translucent navigation bar--as a result, my table view is displayed behind the navigation bar and it's height includes the height of the navigation bar.  However, I want the table view to appear below the navigation bar (as it would if it were not translucent).

I'm working in MonoTouch, but I think the principles are language independent.  Here's the code I'm using to resize the UITableView frame:

```
RectangleF rect = tableView.Frame;
tableView.Frame = new RectangleF (rect.Left, rect.Top + 44, rect.Width, rect.Height - 44);
tableView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets (0, 0, 0, 0);
```

This works fine if I place it in the viewDidAppear method, but will not work in the viewWillAppear method.  In the viewDidAppear method, however I can see the resize occurring briefly in the form of a flicker.  I want to do the resize before the frame appears.  But if I put this code in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad, it has no effect.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: After some more searching it appears to relevant to add that a UITableViewController descendant manages my UITableView.  Is this the problem child?  Are there methods I can override to prevent it from resizing my table?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom tableHeaderView to the table that's the same height as the navigation bar (44 pixels). That will push down the rest of the table.

Comment: I tried this, but had several problems.  I want things that scroll up from my table to be blocked by the navigation bar (it's translucent to allow a background from a parent view to show through).  Specifically, I have a search bar at the top of my table that looks bad when it's behind the navigation bar.  Since I default to it being scrolled behind the bar (like in contacts), my view looks poor in it's default condition. I need the searchbar to be entirely gone when it scrolls off.  Also, I want the section headers to stop at the navigation bar, not appear underneath it as I scroll.